# Bind drop down list using model and stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to bind drop down list using model and stored procedure,I am getting the result but am not sure how do I pass it to the view through models and don't wanna use ViewBag.

My Model

```
public class Revision
{
public List<string> FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Action

```
    public ActionResult Revision()
    {
     var model = new Revision();

     List<Revision> result = db.Database.SqlQuery<Revision>("usp_getName").ToList();
     model.FirstName = result.ToList();

     return View(model);
    }
```

I am getting the result but how do I pass it to my model,I am getting conversion errors I tried

```
model.FirstName = (Revision)result;
model.FirstName = result.ToList();
```

How do I fix this what am I doing wrong.

@Stephen It works correctly but while binding on the view I get System.String does not contain a property with the name FirstName I used

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FirstName, new SelectList(Model.FirstName, "FirstName", "FirstName"))
```

Stored Procedure

```
select FirstName from Customers
```

Comment: Your property is `List<string>` but your query returns List<Revision>` (they are not the same) - You query probably needs to be `db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("usp_getName")` but you have not shown the SP so impossible to tell. In any case, you need 2 properties in your model to use a dropdown list (the property to bind to, and the collection to generate the options)

Comment: That wont work (and edit your question to show the code - not in comments). Your model needs a property to bind to which is `string someProperty` and then it needs to be just `new SelectList(Model.FirstName)` but your property names make so sense. You should have something like `string FirstName` and `List<string> FirstNameList`

Comment: Hi have modified my solution after your feedback,please check above am getting problem when binding it to the View.

Comment: See my last comment :)

Comment: Ok, understood I was adding FirstName twice as DataTextField and DataValue Field.Thats why it was not working.Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: You need to take note of the comment in your last question. Go to the MVC and work through the tutorials so you understand the basics. None of your code makes any sense.